# Lambda function updating, publishing, versioning question

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Would someone please clarify what happens when you update a Lambda function? Do you HAVE to "Publish a new version from $LATEST"? Or will the changes be available as soon as you hit Save?

The confirmation message in the Publish dialog sounds like something I don't want to do...

`Publishing a new version saves a snapshot of the code and configuration of the $LATEST version. You can't edit the new version's code. Click to confirm.`

and I'm being cautious because this is my first serious Lambda.

I have read the AWS page on versioning, but I'm still confused: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hitting save overwrites `$LATEST`.

Once you publish a version, a copy of `$LATEST` is made, and it's assigned a new numeric version identifier.  That new numbered version is frozen, immutable, and can't be edited -- but you can still always edit `$LATEST`.

Invoking the function *and specifying* that assigned version number (it's on the end of the ARN) will thus always run exactly that same immutable code and associated configuration -- unless you subsequently delete the version.

This is just an informational message.  You aren't going to make a mistake by publishing a new version.

Comment: Thanks @michael-sqlbot. Okay, so I presume two things: by not specifying the version number it will always invoke the latest _published_ version of the Lambda function. Roger that!

Comment: Not the latest published numeric version, if that's what you mean.  It should always invoke `$LATEST` if called unqualified.

Comment: Okay. I think this has sunk in. `$LATEST` is what you have when you hit Save. A numbered version when you Publish. You can specify the version arn if you need to invoke a specific version of the function. Thanks again.

Comment: This seems to have changed. Can anyone confirm? I am not able to publish a saved version anymore, and now `$LATEST` points to the last *deployed* version, not the last saved version!